# C# TCP консольный сервер: как принимать команды и их данные от Unity клиентов

Tags: c#, сервер, tcp

Помогите люди! на С# хочу написать консольный TCP сервер для множества юнити клиентов, кто знает правильный ли способ принимать сериализованные данные и обрабатывать таким вот способом их через switch? Как вообще принять в одном потоке и команду и данные?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вам надо обязательно TCP? Почему бы не HTTP?

Comment: switch всегда можно поменять, например, на dictionary

Comment: @tym32167 Можно поподробнее с dictionary? как из за ключа можно вызвать нужный метод? по поводу что лучше выбрать TCP или HTTP тоже нужен профессиональный совет, от него буду уже отталкиваться

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, у вас есть класс пакета

```
public sealed class Package
{
    public string Command { get; }
    public string Payload { get; }

    public Package(string command, string payload)
    {
        Command = command;
        Payload = payload;
    }
}
```

И интерфейс для обработки этого пакета

```
public interface IRequestProcessor
{
    Task<Package> Process(Package package);
}
```

Напишем 2 обработчика

```
public class ConsoleWriteLineProcessor : IRequestProcessor
{
    public Task<Package> Process(Package package)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"OUTPUT: {package.Payload}");
        return Task.FromResult(package);
    }
}

public class ConsoleReadLineProcessor : IRequestProcessor
{
    public Task<Package> Process(Package package)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your line");
        var line = Console.ReadLine();
        return Task.FromResult(new Package(package.Command, line));
    }
}
```

Сервер обработки

```
public class Server
{
    public async Task Start()
    {

        var processors = new Dictionary<string, IRequestProcessor>
        {
            {"write", new ConsoleWriteLineProcessor()},
            {"read", new ConsoleReadLineProcessor()}
        };

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your command");
            var command = Console.ReadLine();
            if (command?.ToLower() == "exit") break;

            if (!processors.ContainsKey(command))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("unknown command");
                continue;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter payload");
            var payload = Console.ReadLine();

            var package = new Package(command, payload);
            var proc = processors[command];

            var response = await proc.Process(package);

            Console.WriteLine($"Response command: {response.Command} payload:{response.Payload}");
        }
    }
}
```

И запускаем

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = new Server();
        await server.Start();
    }
}
```

Результат

[image: ....]

Что касается протокола, если вы планируете связь между вашими клиентами и сервером как `запрос от клиента-ответ от сервера` и супер скорость вам не принципиальна, то тогда HTTP ваш выбор, ибо поднять HTTP сервер сейчас дело расплюнуть, тот же asp.net можно использовать.

Comment: спасибо с передачей заголовка и данными вы мне очень помогли, я даже развил ваш совет и можно сделать dictionary хранящий в значении делегаты на нужные функции. Вопрос о HTTP вы имеете ввиду через HTTPListener принимать данные?

Comment: Про http я имел ввиду это https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet